# Add a clikable link on my image

Tags: image, hyperlink

I want to know how I can change these static image in a clikable image to one of my web page. Thanks

```
<div class="section">
        <div id="home-section">
            <div class="home-box">
                <img class="background-view" alt="École et boutique de danse orientale" src="upload/background.jpg">
                <div class="slider-caption">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="flexslider">
                             <ul class="slides">
                                <li>
                                    <p class="flex-caption">École / Boutique</p>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <p class="flex-caption"><span>de</span> Danse Orientale</p>
                                </li>

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>              
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to achieve? Like when you click on the picture you will get to another site/address? 
If so, just wrap your .. with  like for example in your code:

```
<a href="your address">
<img class="background-view" alt="École et boutique de danse orientale" src="upload/background.jpg">
</a>
```